# Standalone Offline Database

Tags: database, database-design, frontend, backend, offline

I need to make a database that has an exe or any executable file that can access my data. It should be able to edit delete add and search for entries. The data would be like a persons name and all the attributes like height weight date of birth etc. How would I make such a database? I dont need to make something very fancy. Just something that can keep track of the attributes. I have looked into WebApps especially MEAN stack but they are not executable and difficult to operate for a novice with a computer.Essentially a database and a front end but need it in the form of a windows application.

Comment: There are numerous programming languages that can be compiled to exe and have libraries for communicating with databases. For example, you could create a database in PostgreSQL and write a front-end in Python. MSSQL Express and C# is another option. Anyway, this question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow since there isn't a single correct answer.

Comment: If you want an executable file without any external database dependencies, then you can look at SQLite database and embed it in your executable https://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Yeah so thats what I did. I needed something extremely simple. I used Python and SQLite. I used Tkinter as the frontend. Both SQLite and Tkinter are in built packages so it was ideal.